# iOS APP cannot launch successfully after updated from Apple Store

Tags: ios, flutter

In my flutter iOS app, every time the app is launched, it would call PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() to get the app documents directory to access to the previously saved data. If I install the app on an iOS device(not update here), the app could work exactly as expected. But if I updated the app from Apple Store or from Xcode, the app cannot longer be launched successfully. When I try to debug, I found the app caught exceptions at working with the drectory returned by PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(). Anybody could give some suggestions for fixing this? Thanks in advance.

For more information, when launched, my app has to execute createSync(recursive=true) if it does not find some app documents directories where I would store user-generated data. The app documents directories are returned by PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory. However, after I updated the app, and when launched the app, PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() could still return a directory which has appropriate pattern, but the returned directory may not be the right directory since my app failed to find previously created folders there, so the app had to create the relevant directory for storing user-generated data again, and then I always got the error as below

```
FileSystemException: Creation failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

when I tried to create the directory with createSync(recursive=true), and no matter the version of path_provider was 1.20 or 1.10, the phenomenon persisted. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error you got is both happened in iOS simulator & iOS device ?

#### Get the path

Would you mind try to run on iOS simulator, and print out the path of the folder you try to access.

#### Open the folder in Finder

And with the printed folder path, you can open the folder with Finder by `Cmd` + `G`.

#### The error

Your mentioned error usually is because accessing the folder `not belong to the app`.

Let's see more after you print out the folder path.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Even though your response does not suit my case, but your words have inspired me to dig more my issue and I managed to fix the bug. Yes, it is my negligence that made my problem. I was foolish to save the directory path in a config file, and then every time I launched the app I would search the path over the file. So this does not work after updating on the physical device, but it works well on the simulator. Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: It will not work on simulator if you restart computer. You should use relative address to app root. The path is changed by system dynamic.